# How Can I Auto-Click a Button on a Web Page?

Tags: javascript

I have a button on a page I own shown below and I added some `Javascript` to the end of the page to click the button when the page is entered, but it doesn't work. I tried 2 `Javascript` methods shown below but neither worked to click the button.

The first try:

```html
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>

<script>
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
</script>
```

The second try:

```html
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>

<script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; ++i) {
  buttons[i].click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine. Any specific error in the console?

Comment: No errors. Maybe I have to mouse over the button and then click it but how do I add code to mouse over the button?

Comment: @GRF see the answer that I posted. is that you want?

Comment: Neither methods work. The actual style for the button is below and even tried using the classname and it doesn't work.

<style>  .mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-current { background-image: url('https://healthycellshealthyyou.buzzsprout.com/player/wave/4?color=%2392ce00'); }  .mejs-playpause-button { background :#92ce00 !important; }</style>

Comment: @GRF I am telling you. you need to add `onclick` to your button. have you checked my answer?

Comment: I don't see onclick in your answer. How do I add onclick in the button style? <style>  .mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail .mejs-time-current { background-image: url('https://healthycellshealthyyou.buzzsprout.com/player/wave/4?color=%2392ce00'); }  .mejs-playpause-button { background :#92ce00 !important; }</style>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just need to determine what do you expect after click! I mean you need to add something like this `onclick="myfunc()"` to the element.

```html
<button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" onclick="myFunc()"></button>

<script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; ++i) {
  buttons[i].click();
}

function myFunc(){
  alert("called");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is working fine.
I have added an onclick event to the button to verify that the button is clicked. you can see that the console log is coming automatically once the code runs indicating that the button is clicked

```html
<button type="button" onclick="console.log('clicked')" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play"></button>

<script>
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
</script>
```